# Capture soap packets over localhost

Tags: localhost, wireshark

I want to capture SOAP packets transmitting over an application running on localhost. So application obviously runs on localhost, even though do I need a Loopback adapter(software)?

Gear:
Windows 8 , wireshark for network capture, JAVA application

So basically this question consist of 2 questions:
1. How to capture soap only packets?
2. How to capture that on localhost?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To capture on loopback on Windows you'll need some additional software beyond pure Wireshark; see http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback for details.

How to capture only SOAP packets depends on how you end up setting up your loopback. Regardless, if you capture everything you can use Wireshark to filter it after the fact with a normal capture filter (the filter "http" is probably good enough).

Comment: Can you be little more specific? What software works at deeper level than wireshark?

Comment: Read the link - Windows does not expose loopback, so you will need additional software to hook into the Windows kernel to get at those packets.